# Why does apprehending a civilian shooter make the police shoot at me?

Tags: watch-dogs

I found a video that shows what happened to me:

I was walking around doing my own thing, when a random civilian pulled a gun, shot 3 or 4 other civilians, and started running. I pursued a few blocks and finally got the takedown.

The police had been called (presumably by someone after the shooting, and I heard their sirens as I chased the guy down). After I got the takedown I waited around to see if they would give me a nod or something... sometimes games have cool little things like that in them, and I enjoy finding them.

Anyway, the police showed up and started shooting me and killed me. Why did they do that? How come they don't do that when I take down other criminals?

Comment: Probably because they didn't program that in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As stated on the Watch Dogs wiki](http://watchdogs.wikia.com/wiki/Chicago_Police_Department):

> If an A.I Criminal is discharging his weapon against Aiden Pearce or anywhere, the civilians will report Aiden Pearce as suspect instead. Thus, Police will arrest/shoot him instead, unless the A.I Criminal is on their path. See below for this.
>
> If an A.I Criminal pulls out a gun and/or shoots, the Police will immediately respond by attacking back. The Police usually never shoots the gangsters or mission enemies who attack Aiden Pearce if they see him. If however, the attackers are attacking the police, Police will respond by attacking back. The Police will never respond to crimes done by civilians or unarmed criminals, whether they kill other civilians or not.

Basically, you're always the bad guy, regardless of the situation. If there is gunfire involved and the police have been called, they're after *you*.